# Action attribute in html form tag is not sending the data in django

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I want to send song.id from each song in an album model but every time I send it, I get A KeyError

**This is what I wrote in details.html**

```
{% if error_message %}
    <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'music:favorite' album.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" id="song{{ song.id }}" name="song" value="{{ song.id }}">
        <label for="song{{ song.id }}">
            {{ song.song_title }}
            {% if song.is_favorite %}
                <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190726/ourmid/pngtree-cute-light-star-with-black-frame-png-image_1633374.jpg">
            {% endif %}
        </label>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Favorite">
</form>
```

**This is my views.py**

```
def favorite(request, album_id):
album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id)
try:
    selected_song = album.song_set.get(pk=request.POST['song'])
except (KeyError, Song.DoesNotExist):
    return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {
        'album':album,
        'error_message':"You did not select a valid song",
        })
else:
    selected_song.is_favorite = True
    selected_song.save()
    return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'album':album})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. So in the form tag, I had to include the method attribute and set it to POST.

**Change**

```
<form action="{% url 'music:favorite' album.id %}">
```

**To**

```
<form action="{% url 'music:favorite' album.id %}" method="POST">
```